# how can I select only the dates?

Tags: angular

I installed a calendar (). I added an alert when clicking on the date, but this alert also appears when I click and change the month. you know how to restrict the alert only on dates

app.component.ts:

```
alert() {this.onConfirm(window.confirm('You are booking a seat  on the day' + this.model1 + ' do you want to confirm?')); }
```

app,component.html:

```
<ngb-datepicker #d1 [(ngModel)]="model1" #c1="ngModel" (click)="alert()" ></ngb-datepicker>
```

in your opinion how can i enable the click only in the date cells or how can i remove the alert in the outside of the dates?

thanks a lot to everyone! :)

Comment: try add <ngb-datepicker #d1 [(ngModel)]="model1" #c1="ngModel" (click)="alert(d1)" ></ngb-datepicker>, and in method alert(d1) {this.onConfirm(window.confirm('You are booking a seat  on the day' + d1.value + ' do you want to confirm?')); }

Comment: hello thanks for the advice but it doesn't work, I need the alert to be activated only on the date and not on the entire calendar content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using (dateSelect) as such <ngb-datepicker (dateSelect)="alert()">